# sending the appropriate model for each partial views that are common to all pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have 2 forms : one to register into the newsletter and other to search on web site :
 http://nsa31.casimages.com/img/2014/02/13/140213065557598803.png

and because i need validation client side and server side i created 2 ViewModels for each forms to specify the validation attributes and Error Messages:

Subscribe Model (file:  SubscribeModel.cs) :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SoscomAppMvc.Models
{
    public class SubscribeModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Veuillez saisir votre adresse mail pour s'inscrire ...")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Veuillez saisir une adresse mail valide \"Ex: mail@domaine.com\"")]
        public string SubEmail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Serach Model (file: SearchModel.cs) :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SoscomAppMvc.Models
{
    public class SearchModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Veuillez saisir votre mot clé avant de lancer la recherche ...")]
        public string Key { get; set; }
    }
}
```

these two forms are rendered into Layout view from 2 partial views:

Subscribe partial view (file: Shared/Subscribe.cshtml) :

```
@model SoscomAppMvc.Models.SubscribeModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Subscribe", "Soscom"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SubEmail, new { placeholder = "Email pour s'inscrire à la newsletter", @class = "subscribebox" })
    <input class="subscribeBtn" type="submit" value="s'inscrire">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SubEmail)
}
```

Search partial view (file: Shared/Serach.cshtml) :

```
@model SoscomAppMvc.Models.SearchModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Soscom", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Key, new { placeholder = "Rechercher un produit, une solution ...", @class = "textfeild" })
    <input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Go">
}
```

Code to render these two partial views into layout page (file: Shared/_Layout.cshtml)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
     ....
     </head>
     <body>
         <header>
             <div id="banner">
                 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Subscribe.cshtml")
             </div>
             <div id="navpan">
                 <nav>
                     <ul>
                         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Soscom", "Index", "Soscom")</li>
                         ....
                     </ul>
                 </nav>
                 <div id="searchbar">
                     @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Search.cshtml")
                 </div>
         </header>
         ....
         <section>
             @RenderBody()
         </section>
         ....
     </body>
</html>
```

I also created 2 actions to handle posted data:

Subscribe action :

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Subscribe(SubscribeModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View("SubscribeErrors", model);

    // saveMailToDB(model.SubEmail)
    return View("SubscribeResult", model);
}
```

Search action :

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Search(SearchModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View("SearchErrors", model);

    // searchFromDB(key, ResultSearchModel); return View(ResultSearchModel); 
    return View("SearchResult");
}
```

now when i run application, everything looks fine, but when i post subscribe form i get this error :

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type "SubscribeModel", but this dictionary requires a model item of type "SearchModel"
```

i get the same error for search form :

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type "SearchModel", but this dictionary requires a model item of type "SubscribeModel"
```

how to get out from this errors,

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. You can't use a partial with a model unless you can feed it that model, some how some way. By default, if you don't pass a model to the partial, Razor will pass the main view's model, which is why you're getting those errors.

You *could* simply pass a new instance of the appropriate model:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Subscribe.cshtml", new Namespace.To.SubscribeModel());
```

But, that's a little clunky. The better method is to use child actions in these scenarios:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Subscribe()
{
    return PartialView("Subscribe", new SubscribeModel());
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.Action("Subscribe", "MyController");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass an empty model to each Partial view. So your _Layout.cshtml should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     ....
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="banner">
                 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Subscribe.cshtml", new SubscribeModel())
            </div>
            ....
            <div id="searchbar">
                 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Search.cshtml", new SearchModel())
            </div>
        </header>
        ....
        <section>
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
        ....
    </body>
</html>
```